# laravel - get last record

Tags: database, laravel

I have this query

```
$user->orders->where('service_id',$request->service_id)->first();
```

I need to get the last element , How can I do that ?

there is no `created_at` column so I can't use `latest()`

Comment: I get this message error     "message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::orderBy does not exist.",

Comment: I'm using laravel-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$user->orders()->where('service_id', $request->service_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
```

Comment: it doesn't work , I get this error     "message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::orderByDesc does not exist.",

Comment: looks you are using an old version of laravel , try this one ,

$user->orders->where('service_id',$request->service_id)->orderBy("id","desc")->first();

Comment: I'm using Laravel 7 , and I get the same error     "message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::orderBy does not exist.",

Comment: Oh Sorry now I see what is The problem .......
try this

 $user->orders()->where('service_id',$request->service_id)->orderBy("id","desc")->first();

Answer (score 9):

Try `latest()` method once more and give them a parameter.

```php
$user->orders()
    ->where('service_id', $request->service_id)
    ->latest('id')
    ->first();
```

Eloquent's `latest()` method:

```php
/**
 * Add an "order by" clause for a timestamp to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @return $this
 */
public function latest($column = null)
{
    if (is_null($column)) {
        $column = $this->model->getCreatedAtColumn() ?? 'created_at';
    }

    $this->query->latest($column);

    return $this;
}
```

This method internally uses `created_at`, but accepts specific column you want. I suggest that use this method rather than `->orderBy()->frist()`. This gives you more readability and maintainability.

Comment: Your answer is great and much simpler, but You just need to add parentheses to this:
***$user->orders()***

Comment: Sure, thanks for suggestion. Parentheses have been added if @Matrix wants to query on the Order relation.